# How to partially mock service in Grails integration test

Tags: grails, groovy, spock

I am attempting to write a test for a controller which calls a service method.  I would like to mock a dependent method within that service.

My spec is as follows:

```
MyController myController = new MyController()
def mockMyService

def "My spy should be called"() {
    when:
        mockMyService = Spy(MyService) {
            methodToSpy() >> {
                println "methodToSpy called"
            } // stub out content of this fn
        }
        myController.myService = mockMyService
        myController.callService()

    then:
        1 * mockMyService.methodToSpy()
}
```

When I attempt to run this test, I get the following error:

```
Failure:  |
My spy should be called(spybug.MyControllerSpec)
 |
Too few invocations for:
1 * mockMyService.methodToSpy()   (0 invocations)
Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):
1 * mockMyService.serviceMethod()
1 * mockMyService.invokeMethod('methodToSpy', [])
1 * mockMyService.invokeMethod('println', ['in serviceMethod about to call methodToSpy'])
1 * mockMyService.invokeMethod('println', ['Back from methodToSpy'])
```

As you can see, Spock is capturing the Groovy invokeMethod call, not the subsequent call to the actual method.  Why is this happening?

The complete project is available [here](https://github.com/mmigdol/spyBug).

Comment: You are writing a unit or integration test?

Comment: did you ever manage to find a solution to this? It seems that I have just asked a similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59030447/how-can-i-mock-a-grails-4-service-in-a-grails-4-controller-unit-test

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def "My spy should be called"() {
    given:
    mockMyService = Mock(MyService)
    myController.myService = mockMyService

    when:
    myController.callService()

    then:
    1 * mockMyService.methodToSpy(_) >> { println "methodToSpy called" }   
}
```

According to the spock documentation for stubs, if you want to use the cardinality, you must use a Mock and not a Stub.

http://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html#_stubbing

Comment: No, I want to make sure that MyService.callService invokes methodToSpy.  Mocking the entire service only allows me to confirm that callService() was called, not that callService invokes methodToSpy()

Comment: No problem.  FWIW, I'm cognizant of the warning in the [Spock Interactions Documentation](http://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html) that states `(Think twice before using this feature. It might be better to change the design of the code under specification.)`  But I think partials are still useful in some situations and would like to get this working...

Comment: Have you tried using GroovySpy?  I do a lot of testing with Spock and in my experience using Spies for partial mocking has worked only in 20% cases, with all kinds of weird failures like this one in other cases. In the end, I am overriding methods of subjects under test with metaClass changes and cleaning that up after the test.