# How can I mock a grails 4 service in a controller unit test

Tags: spring, unit-testing, grails, groovy, mocking

I don't understand how mocking works in Grails 4.0.
I have this unit test that fails (it is just an illustration of the real test, the real test actually involves the controller):

```
import com.myapp.MySearchService

class ApiControllerSpec extends Specification implements ControllerUnitTest<ApiController> {

    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "test listSources"() {
        given:
        def mock = Mock(MySearchService) {
            find(_) >> [["label": "abc", "description": "xsad"]]
        }

        when:
        System.out.println(mock.find(''))

        then:
        1 * mock.find(_) >> [["label": "abc", "description": "xsad"]]
    }
```

with error

```
Too few invocations for:

1 * mock.find(_) >> [["label": "abc", "description": "xsad"]]   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

1 * mock.invokeMethod('find', [<java.lang.String@0 value= hash=0>])


    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.InteractionScope.verifyInteractions(InteractionScope.java:93)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.MockController.leaveScope(MockController.java:77)
    at toe.ApiControllerSpec.test listSources(ApiControllerSpec.groovy:29)
```

and stdout

```
null
```

The interesting thing is that *this works fine if I use a very simple test class instead of MySearchService*. So I am assuming that it has to do something with the way Grails/Spring is setup. This might also explain the lines:

```
Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

1 * mock.invokeMethod('find', [<java.lang.String@0 value= hash=0>])
```

But how do I set it up otherwise? I can't find this anywhere in the documentation. Thanks for any help!

Similar question (without answer):
[How to partially mock service in Grails integration test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32104348/how-to-partially-mock-service-in-grails-integration-test)

Comment: "So I am assuming that it has to do something with the way Grails/Spring is setup." - I don't think that is the case.  I don't thing Spring is relevant and really neither is Grails.  See Eric's answer below which clarifies what is going on.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax for your mock is incorrect - here's a working example tested in Grails 4.0.1

```
    void "test something"() {
        given:
        def mock = Mock(SearchService) {
            1 * find(_) >> ['foobar'] // note the interaction count is required when defining this way.
        }

        when:
        def result = mock.find('')

        then:
        result == ['foobar']
    }
```

See - http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html - Section: `Declaring Interactions at Mock Creation Time`

Note this is likely not in the Grails docs as there is nothing Grails specific about it - just Spock.

Answer (score 0):

here is already a workaround that is not great:

```
    void "test listSources"() {
        given:
        def mock = Mock(MySearchService) {
            invokeMethod('find', _) >> [["label": "abc", "description": "xsad"]]
        }

        when:
        System.out.println(mock.find(''))

        then:
        1 * mock.invokeMethod('find', _) >> [["label": "abc", "description": "xsad"]]
    }
```